# Eclipse Remote debugging where java application deployed in linux machine

Tags: eclipse

How can I debug Java Application Running in Linux machine with Eclipse in windows.

I am doing the following thing but get the following exception:-  **Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out. org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException...**

**Step Taken**

1) Eclipse installed in Widows 7 (IP: XX.XX.XX.74,  JAVA version 6)

2) Java Application running in Linux machine (IP: XX.XX.XX.246,  JAVA version 6) and JAVA_OPTS used:-

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9000,server=y,suspend=y"
```

when I run the java application on Linux machine, it is listening on port 9000.

3) Eclipse Debug configuration used : `Host-XX.XX.XX.246; Port-9000, Connection Type-Standard(Socket Attached)`

4) I also use following command in Linux:

```
**iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT**  to bypass 9000 port from firewall
```

Comment: could you use telnet to test port access permission?